# How do I query a Domain Controlers NTP service from a linux box?

Tags: linux, ntp

I need to confirm that a Domain Controller is acting as a NTP time server for non windows devices and servers. I figure there must be a command in linux that will query an NTP server and see if it is accessible and serving the right time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned `ntpdate` is a standard tool for requesting the time, and using it to set your local system.

If you have the full NTP daemon installed, you could update your `ntp.conf` restart the daemon, and then query the status of your local daemon with `ntpq -p`.

If you want to continuously monitor NTP, then https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/ includes check commands for monitoring various aspects of NTP [check_ntp](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_ntp.html), [check_ntp_peer](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_ntp_peer.html), and [check_ntp_time](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_ntp_time.html).  This plugin package is available on most linux distros.  Though it may go by the older name nagios-plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the ntp package installed. You can then run the following as root

```
ntpdate -q ip.of.server
```

Comment: This would set the time on the querying machine - probably not an intended outcome.

Comment: this did what I wanted.  I just wanted to prove that a non windows client could query time.  I just did it on a test linux box